# Last number in barcode

Tags: algorithm

Find solution, how work algoritem for last, control number in 8 places barcode.
Here is some results:

1. Here we got last number 8[image: Example 1]
2. Here we got last number 7: [image: Example 2]
3. Here we got last number 5 [image: Example3]

What is last number of this 2 Barcode?

1. [image: Barcode 1]

and this

2. [image: Barcode 2]

> Try multiply some numbers with 3

Comment: Finding industry barcode algorithms is not a puzzle.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's not a puzzle.

Comment: I have a feeling that if the answer wasn't publicly available information, the three examples given would not have been enough to figure it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The barcode checksum is derived through the following process:

1. Add the digits at odd positions, then multiply by 3.
2. Add the digits at even positions to your answer.
3. 10 minus your result, modulo 10, is the check digit.

So for the first one: $ 10 -( ((5+1+4+8)\times3 + 1 + 8 + 3) \mod 10)=7$

And for the second: $10- (((5+0+2+4)\times 3 + 7 + 1 + 3
)\mod 10) = 6$

Comment: You have right, but only first one you write 1 not 0.

Answer (score 0):

Pretty sure its:

> 1.  5

and

> 2.  0

Just by looking at previous numbers.

Comment: @Deusovi why did I get a downvote for answering?

Comment: Because this answer is wrong.

Comment: Someone needs their 886609 546***. Sheesh.

Comment: You need to provide justification for why you think the answer is correct. "Just by looking at previous numbers" is not helpful.

Comment: Yah. I didn't assume it was necessary after it was pointed out to be wrong and the right answer was already posted. I looked at the section of the barcode over the blank space and attempted to match to a known number.